# Python Server with multithreads : WinError 10038 on exit (closing socket)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, client-server, serversocket

I am trying to create a server which will handle communication with multiple clients.
This app is running face detection via cv2 library and if it detects face it would send image as an byte array to all active (connected) clients.
I have two infitite (while True) loops here - one for face detection on main "thread" and another one on which runs on Thread from threading library, there my server socket is accepting all new clients.
I have problem when I press  button to exit the app i get following error:

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-cff9bdsm\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

Successfully closed server application
Exception in thread Thread-1:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Slavujevic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Slavujevic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File ".\Server.py", line 51, in clientReceivement
    client, address = serversock.accept()
  File "C:\Users\Slavujevic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 292, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

this is my code:

```
#face detection dependencies
import cv2
import numpy as np

#TCP/IP socket communication dependencies
import socket
from threading import Thread
import threading
import time

#face detection classifier
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
#WebCam handler
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#socket server's IP address & port 
port = 21000
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name

#socket initialisation
clients = set()
clients_lock = threading.Lock()

global serversock
serversock = socket.socket()
serversock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serversock.bind(('',port))
serversock.listen(3)
th = []

def listener(client, address):
    global img
    print ("\nAccepted connection from: ", address,'\n')
    with clients_lock:
        clients.add(client)
    try:    
        while True:
            data = client.recv(1024)
            if int(data) == 0:
                msg = "HI :)"
                print('\nSENDING: ', str(msg),'\n')
                #char = str(int(catch))
                client.send(bytes(msg,encoding='utf8'))
    except ValueError:
        print("\nClient Disconnected\n")

def clientReceivement():

    print ("\nWaiting for new clients...\n")
    while True:
        client, address = serversock.accept()
        th.append(Thread(target=listener, args = (client,address)).start())


th.append(Thread(target=clientReceivement).start())
while True:
    global img
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for(x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
serversock.close()

print("\nSuccessfully closed server application\n")
exit()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to `join()` any of the threads at some point? I believe that error indicates that close() was called before accept().

Comment: Hi, thanks for question. Is that necessary because all of my threads run on infinite loops? Also, can you please share example how would I do that for my th list? Would it affect my exit error?